# css and basket: how to do an "always visible" basket?

Tags: css, shopping-cart

Here on this site, if you try any restaurant, you'll see a basket that is always visible on the right, and if you scroll down, then it's "magical": it stays like "sticky" on the top of the screen. http://takeaway.com

How did they do that, and do you have any good sites/tutorials to do such things (I don't know what to google actually!)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the browser scrolls past a certain point, this following CSS is applied to the basket:

```
position: fixed; top: 0px;
```

You can do this fairly easily using jQuery plugins like Waypoints, which has a special functionality for creating "sticky" elements.

Get the plugin and see tutorials here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

See the example here: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

Answer (score 1):

You want exactly what I did in my project have a look at [project](http://homecollective.in/) we have used the similar thing with our shopping cart. We have used the following css key point is Position and z-index

```
#your wrapper{
    margin:0 0 14px 0px;
    /*margin: 30px auto;*/
}
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:-30px;
    width:74%;
    left:13%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```